# Python 3: Tkinter - Imagem de fundo não existe, "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, gui

Meu código para exibir uma imagem de fundo:

```
    from tkinter import *
    def entrar():
      #Janela Principal
      janela = Tk()
      janela.title("Salvadados")
      janela.geometry('400x600')
      #fotofundo
      back = Label(janela)
      back.la = PhotoImage(file = 'C:/Users/Ivan/Videos/fundim2.gif')
      back['image'] = back.la
      back.place(x=0,y=0)
```

O seguinte erro é exibido:

```
 **File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1473, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist**
```

Observação: a função entrar() é um comando para um botão abrir essa janela "Salvadados".

Answer (score 1):

Apenas o código que você mostrou funciona perfeitamente. Certamente, existe muito mais código do seu programa que você não mostrou.

Grande parte das vezes, este erro ocorre quando você cria uma ou mais janelas com o `Tk` ou então quando você destrói a atual, cria uma nova e reutiliza o PhotoImage anterior. Exemplo:

## Esse código gera o mesmo erro que você mostrou porque é criado 2 janelas:

```
from tkinter import *

def entrar():

  #Janela Principal
  janela = Tk()
  janela.title("Salvadados")
  janela.geometry('400x600')

  #fotofundo
  back = Label(janela)
  back.la = PhotoImage(file = 'image.png')
  back['image'] = back.la
  back.place(x=0,y=0)

root = Tk()
entrar()
```

## Esse código gera erro pois eu tento reutilizar o PhotoImage anterior:

```
from tkinter import *

def entrar():

  #Janela Principal
  janela = Tk()
  janela.title("Salvadados")
  janela.geometry('400x600')

  #fotofundo
  back = Label(janela)
  back.la = PhotoImage(file = 'C:/Users/Jean Extreme/Desktop/Jean Extreme/Extreme/Fotos/Placa Minecraft Like.png')
  back['image'] = back.la
  back.place(x=0,y=0)
  return janela,back


root , back = entrar()
root.destroy()

new_root = Tk()
label = Label(new_root)
label["image"] = back.la
label.pack()
```

## Esse código não gera erro:

```
from tkinter import *

def entrar():

  #Janela Principal
  janela = Tk()
  janela.title("Salvadados")
  janela.geometry('400x600')

  #fotofundo
  back = Label(janela)
  back.la = PhotoImage(file = 'image.png')
  back['image'] = back.la
  back.place(x=0,y=0)

entrar()
```

Para corrigir o problema você não deve criar mais de uma janela com o tkinter e sempre que for destruir uma janela para criar outra, crie também um novo `PhotoImage`.